# Label Vertical alignment not working

Tags: codenameone

I have a Label with an Icon and I was trying to set the vertical alignment at the bottom, but it is not working. Is is an issue?

```
Form hi = new Form("Label");
hi.add(new Button("Upper Border"));
Label bottomLabel = new Label("Label Text Bottom");
bottomLabel.setIcon(theme.getImage("Orange Line.png"));
bottomLabel.setVerticalAlignment(Component.BOTTOM);
hi.add(bottomLabel);
hi.add(new Button("Bottom Border"));
hi.show();
```

[image]

**EDITED**

I am not looking to achieve the exact layout shown in the above picture. That was just an example of what I need. I would like to be able to add a label with an Icon and set the text on the bottom. But I don't want to do that using Containers, because I need to add several lines containing the Icon and the text at the bottom. An example below of what I want to learn to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use borderlayout to set the label at the bottom of the form which is shown in below codes . I have changed layout of form and set the label the bottom

```
    Form hi = new Form("Label");
    **hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());**
    hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,new Button("Upper Border"));
    Label bottomLabel = new Label("Label Text Bottom");
    bottomLabel.setIcon(theme.getImage("Orange Line.png"));
    bottomLabel.setVerticalAlignment(Component.BOTTOM);
    **hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,bottomLabel);**
   //hi.add(new Button("Bottom Border"));
    hi.show();
```

Comment: But what about the code? It is correct, right? Is so, why is it not working?

Comment: The code can not set component at both upper and bottom border .To set the upper and bottom border you need to set borderlayout .

Comment: @Felipe label alignment is really text alignment against an icon not absolutely within the label so your code shouldn't work like that. tizbn's answer is indeed correct

Comment: @tizbn Please see my edited text. The picture was only an example. Shouldn't setVerticalAlignment() work on the text relative to the Icon?